# Show a "Last Updated Date" on the website

Tags: dotnetnuke

I would like to have a "Last Updated Date" on my site. As we are updating data in edition, concern table ([HtmlText] having CreatedDate) has been updated. I'm looking for an analogous approach for this use of Tokens but I did not find any setting regarding this which can display CreatedDate.

I am using:

- Sql Server 2008
- DotNetNuke_Community_04.09.05_Source
- ISS V5.1
- Visual Studio 2008

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write a custom skin object that looked at all the MODULES on the page, as well as the Page Settings, to get the latest Last Updated date.

This isn't a simple thing to do in DNN because some modules don't have any record of when they were last updated, it depends on the module developer who created them.

Also you should seriously consider upgrading off of DNN 4, it is very old and has security bugs.

Comment: Hi Chris,Thanks for updating. Can you provide me some sample code. Also i try to download Latest versions, but there was no bin folder. Please suggest whether how to update this, so that existing functionaly will not hamper as we create n no of pages in this site.

Comment: You downloaded the latest version of DNN and there was no BIN folder? Download the INSTALL package not SOURCE.